# sort a list using XSL

Tags: xslt

I am in the learning phase of XSL. I am facing a problem where I need to sort elements, depending on their date. The input XML contains lists. Each object in list contains a complex object. I need to sort the list based on the element in complex object.
E.g
    
    `<list>
      <object>
        <date>2011-10-05<date/>
      </object>
    </list>
    <list>
      <object>
        <date>2011-10-04<date/>
      </object>
    </list>
    <list>
      <object>
        <date>2011-10-08<date/>
      </object>

    </list>`

I need to sort the xml based on date. Is it possible to do?. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

You can use multiple xsl:sort element in order to sort your selection with multiple criteria.

The following 1.0 XSLT transform :

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
      <xsl:for-each select="root/list">
        <xsl:sort data-type="number" order="ascending" select="substring(normalize-space(object/date), 1, 4)"/>
        <xsl:sort data-type="number" order="ascending" select="substring(normalize-space(object/date), 6, 2)"/>
        <xsl:sort data-type="number" order="ascending" select="substring(normalize-space(object/date),9, 2)"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </root>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to the .xml file I came up with based on your ill formed input :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <list>
    <object>
      <date>
        2011-10-05
      </date>
    </object>
  </list>
  <list>
    <object>
      <date>
        2011-10-04
      </date>
    </object>
  </list>
  <list>
    <object>
      <date>
        2011-10-08
      </date>
    </object>
  </list>
</root>
```

Will produce the following result :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <list>
      <object>
         <date>
        2011-10-04
      </date>
      </object>
  </list>
   <list>
      <object>
         <date>
        2011-10-05
      </date>
      </object>
  </list>
   <list>
      <object>
         <date>
        2011-10-08
      </date>
      </object>
  </list>
</root>
```

I am sorting first based on year then on month and finally on day. Naturally you can alter the sorting order to suit your needs.

I hope I could solve your problem :)